# App Store not updating screenshots.

Tags: ios, iphone

I added the  new screenshots for updated version . My App update was approved yesterday . The new screenshot is showing on my itunes account  but not in the App store .

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, did you solve the problem ?

Comment: Yes , We raised the query to Apple Support Team for the same . Then after one day the updated images was there on App store.

Comment: I also have the same problem, should i raise the query to Apple Support Team?

Comment: @Mak13 yes, they will update

Comment: @PritiKanauziya- how do i do it? Can u plz guide me. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Mak13  write mail for  Apple Support Team and describe them your problem. Also make sure your AppStore have updated images.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having a similar issue but when I view them in "View All Sizes in Media Manager" I can see old screenshots for 4" display and 3.5" display.

After removed old screenshot I see new screenshots.

Hope this answer will help.

Answer (score 0):

I was running a test on "Product Page Optimization" which was serving the old screenshots. Once removed, the screenshots returned as should